# How do you resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my Error

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.messaging.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.messaging-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.messaging-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code snippets or context around what you were doing when this error occurred, it can be quite difficult to say how to resolve it, however I will do my best to point you in the right direction.

#### What is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`?

According to [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-solve-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-in-java/), the path being specified to load the file does not seem to contain the file that the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) is looking for.

#### What Can You Do About It?

- **Change the file path to accurately reflect where the file is found** (*keeping in mind that different operating systems may arrive at the same destination with minor variations in syntax, e.g. C:\Path\AnotherPath on Windows or usr/path/anotherpath on Linux distributions*)
- **Check to see if the file is actually at the location you specified, assuming the path is correct**.  Follow the path on your machine to the directory specified and make sure that the file is there.
- **In the case of the file not being there, either change the path to where the file is actually found or simply move the file to that destination**.
- **If none of the above has worked, perhaps you lost the file or deleted it accidentally, in which case I suggest a rollback on the project or simply starting it up again from scratch if you weren't too far along with it**.